# Angular service that is instantiated on every page change/request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm making my first steps in [AngularJS (1.5)](https://angularjs.org/) and I'm trying to build a feature that will let me change few things in my layout based on the route.

As far as I understood I needed a service for this. Basically the setup I have is:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'appControllers',
  'AppServices'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: '<h1>Home page</h1>',
    controller: 'MainController'
  }).when('/page', {
    template: '<h1>Page</h1>',
    controller: 'PagesController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('MainController', ['$rootScope', 'AppSetup', function($scope, AppSetup) {
  $scope.app = AppSetup.build();
  console.log('home');
}]);

appControllers.controller('PagesController', ['$rootScope', 'AppSetup', function($scope, AppSetup) {
  AppSetup.setProperties({
    meta: {
      title: 'My Second Page'
    }
  });
  console.log('page');
  $scope.app = AppSetup.build();
}]);

var AppServices = angular.module('AppServices', []);

AppServices.service('AppSetup', [function() {
  var properties = {
      meta: {
        title: 'My App &bull; Best of the best'
      }
    },
    styles;
  this.setProperties = function(input) {
    this.properties = angular.extend(properties, input);
  };
  //TODO: This will override app-wide styles.
  this.setStyles = function(input) {
    this.styles = angular.extend({}, input);

  };
  this.build = function() {
    return {
      properties: properties,
      styles: styles
    };
  };
}]);
```

[Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vrASK9N5bjXcxC8z2R0i?p=preview)

So I have one defined `properties` object and want to override it when I visit a page. The problem is that when I go back to home, it doesn't set the default value. Obviously it's instantiated once the page is loaded and then remains the same until changed.
What's the best approach to do this?

I have tried adding a listener to the route, as @Raul A. suggested, but it's not working. Output from console:

[image]

[Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vrASK9N5bjXcxC8z2R0i)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $routeChangeSuccess event if you are using routing and make changes in the function watching for it:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(currentRoute, previousRoute){
   //Do you changes here 
});
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I have edited my question with the result. Looks like if I open `/page` directly it gets the values from `MainController` instead of `PagesController`.